# changes.list : difference between startChangeId and pageToken

Tags: google-drive-api

While playing with the API explorer on the changes.list endpoint, i noticed that `startChangeId` and `pageToken` cause the same response from the server.

Let's say I execute the request with the parameter `startChangeId = 700`. I will have the exact same response if I execute the request with `pageToken = 700`.

Can anyone tell me if there is an actual difference between the two parameters ? And if yes, what are the best practices regarding those two parameters ?